# Count occurrence of numbers in linux

Tags: linux, count

I have a .txt file with 25,000 lines. Each line there is a number from 1 to 20. I want to compute the total occurrence of each number in the file. I don't know should I use grep or awk and how to use it. And I'm worried about I got confused with 1 and 11, which both contain 1's. Thank you very much for helping!

I was trying but this would double count my numbers.

```
grep -o '1' degreeDistirbution.txt | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

With grep you can match the beginning and end of a line with '^' and '$' respectively. For the whole thing I'll use an array, but to illustrate this point I'll just use one variable:

```
one="$(grep -c "^1$" ./$inputfile)"
```

then we put that together with the magic of bash loops and loop through all the numbers with a while like so:

```
i=1
while [[ $i -le 20 ]]
do
  arr[i]="$(grep -c "^$i$" ./$inputfile)"
  i=$[$i+1]
done
```

if you like you can of course use a for as well

Answer (score 1):

An easier method is:

```
sort -n file | uniq -c
```

Which will count the occurrences of each number in the sorted file and display the results like:

```
$ sort -n dat/twenty.txt | uniq -c
      3 1
      3 2
      3 3
      4 4
      4 5
      4 6
      4 7
      4 8
      4 9
      4 10
      4 11
      3 12
      2 13
      2 14
      4 15
      4 16
      4 17
      2 18
      2 19
      2 20
```

Showing I have 3 ones, 3 twos, etc.. in the sample file.

Comment: Sure, I almost fainted the first time I saw that trick after spending time messing around with loops, etc.. There are an amazing number of command line tools Linux offers that can solve just about any text manipulation problem you run across. When you stumble across a question like this -- chances are a Linux dev has as well -- and those Linux devs are pretty good about coding little tools to solve just about anything `:p`